# Accept decimal with comma and dot (html)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need some help with this input because I want it only accept 2 decimals and comma or dot as well, but now just allow comma instead of a dot and any decimals. I'm extremely new with RegExp and I was trying with this.

```
<td>
    <input type="number" ng-model="material.porcentaje" ng-change="calculaKilos(material, $index);validatePorcentaje($index)" id="porcentaje" class="input_small-stretch" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `,` to `type="number"`. You need to change it to `type="text"` and then `onkeyup` you can check if there are any values other than numbers and comma you can replace it with `''`

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup',(e)=>{
 let value = e.target.value;
 e.target.value = value.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g,'');;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="material.porcentaje" ng-change="calculaKilos(material, $index);validatePorcentaje($index)" id="porcentaje" class="input_small-stretch" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to help build your Regular Expression pattern. I could try to build the pattern for you, but without example text it is difficult.